# Make 3 columns change into accordion when resized

Tags: html, css, responsive

I need the display of a 3 column page to turn into an accordion when viewed on a smart phone.  I've looked to see if there were any examples or tutorials but I haven't run into any.  I've found changing tabs into accordions, but, this is a basic page that has 3 columns and when it is resized to a smaller screen size it needs to change into an accordion.  Any links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes indeed you can! Do you have any examples of things you have already tried?

Comment: No.  I haven't found anything yet.  That's the problem.  The only thing I can find is turning tabs into an accordion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox` to do this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > div {
  flex: 1;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transition: flex 0.5s;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container > div {
    flex: 0;
  }
  .container > div:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .container:hover > div {
    flex: 0;
  }
  .container > div:hover {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left">Left</div>
      <div class="middle">Middle</div>
      <div class="right">Right</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**index.html**

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section section--1">Section 1</div>
      <div class="section section--2">Section 2</div>
      <div class="section section--3">Section 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**style.css**

```
.container {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 24px;
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}

.section--1 { background-color: red; }
.section--2 { background-color: blue; }
.section--3 { background-color: green; }

/* small screen */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

I hope I have been able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, but, I need once it resizes for the smaller screen to become an accordion.  I haven't been able to find an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a few lines of jQuery to add the `collapse` value to Bootstrap's `data-toggle` attribute when viewing on a screen 480px (or whatever width you want) or smaller.

```
  $(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 480) {
        $("#col1, #col2").attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
    }
  })
```

**Note**: You have to refresh your page if you're just resizing your browser (and be sure you resize the Fiddle results window to smaller than 480px to see the effect), but it would still make your columns accordions on mobile devices while displaying things normally on larger screens.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suL0akav/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's taken so long to get back to you.  All of the suggested code is great.  What I ended up doing is I hid the accordion and had it become visible at the mobile size and then the main content was hidden.  Just used css.